# Python segmentation fault:11 for simple terminal calculations

Tags: python, macos, terminal, segmentation-fault

I go to terminal on my mac and type `python`.  The standard stuff shows up:

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Now I am using the terminal to do simple calculations.  I simply type in the following below and keep getting a segmentation fault 11.  It seems to be from the decimal point I keep inserting.

```
>>> a=1./2
>>> b=2./3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  I never had this happen before.  How else would you force floating point numbers?  Thank you

Comment: You're on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), aren't you? There's a well known issue with python and Mavericks. You'll need to `easy_install readline`

Comment: Or just update to 2.7.6.

Comment: Or just uninstall your third-party Python 2.7.3 and use the 2.7.5 that comes with Mavericks instead of trying to maintain two separate 2.7s.

Comment: Yeah, but there are other reasons why you might need to continue to use a python.org Python, for example, if you are using binary installers of packages like NumPy that depend on the python.org version.

Comment: And, if you are a beginner and planning to use `IDLE`, the system `IDLE` uses the broken system version of `Tk` that can crash if you type the right characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing this on OS X 10.9 Mavericks, you are running into [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue18458) with python.org Pythons, caused by a change in the system `editline` library, `libedit`.  A solution is to [download](http://www.python.org/download/) and install the latest version, Python 2.7.6, which has a fix for this problem.